# how to implement this future/state concept as a monad in scala

Tags: scala, monads

I'm trying to implement a container for a match (like in sports) result so that I can create matches between the winners of other matches. This concept is close to what a future monads is as it contains a to be defined value, and also close to a state monad as it hides state change. Being mostly a begginer on the topic I have implemented an initial version in scala that is surely improvable. I added a get method that I'm not sure was a good idea, and so far the only way to create a value would be `Unknown(null)` which is not as elegant as I'd hoped. What do you think I could do to improve this design?

```
case class Unknown[T](t : T) {
  private var value : Option[T] = Option(t)
  private var applicatives: List[T => Unit] = Nil

  def set(t: T) {
    if (known) {
      value = Option(t)
      applicatives.foreach(f => f(t))
      applicatives = Nil
    } else {
      throw new IllegalStateException
    }
  }

  def get : T = value.get

  def apply(f: T => Unit) = value match {
    case Some(x) => f(x);
    case None => applicatives ::= f
  }

  def known = value == None
}
```

**UPDATE**: a usage example of the current implementation follows

```
case class Match(val home: Unknown[Team], val visit: Unknown[Team], val result: Unknown[(Int, Int)]) {
  val winner: Unknown[Team] = Unknown(null)
  val loser: Unknown[Team] = Unknown(null)

  result.apply(result => {
    if (result._1 > result._2) {
      home.apply(t => winner.set(t))
      visit.apply(t => loser.set(t))
    } else {
      home.apply(t => loser.set(t))
      visit.apply(t => winner.set(t))
    }
  })
}
```

And a test snippet:

```
val definedUnplayedMatch = Match(Unknown(Team("A")), Unknown(Team("B")), Unknown(null));
val definedPlayedMatch = Match(Unknown(Team("D")), Unknown(Team("E")), Unknown((1,0)));
val undefinedUnplayedMatch = Match(Unknown(null), Unknown(null), Unknown(null));

definedUnplayedMatch.winner.apply(undefinedUnplayedMatch.home.set(_))
definedPlayedMatch.winner.apply(undefinedUnplayedMatch.visit.set(_))
undefinedUnplayedMatch.result.set((3,1))
definedUnplayedMatch.result.set((2,4))
undefinedUnplayedMatch.winner.get must be equalTo(Team("B")); 
undefinedUnplayedMatch.loser.get must be equalTo(Team("D"));
```

**UPDATE - CURRENT IDEA :** I haven't had much time to work on this because my laptop broke down, but I though it would be useful to write the monad I have so far for those who are interested:

```
sealed abstract class Determine[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Determine[B]
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Determine[B]): Determine[B]
  def filter(p: A => Boolean): Determine[A]
  def foreach(b: A => Unit): Unit
}
final case class Known[+A](value: A) extends Determine[A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Determine[B] = Known(f(value))
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Determine[B]): Determine[B] = f(value)
  def filter(p: A => Boolean): Determine[A] = if (p(value)) this else Unknown
  def foreach(b: A => Unit): Unit = b(value)
}
final case class TBD[A](definer: () => A) extends Determine[A] {
  private var value: A = _

  def map[B](f: A => B): Determine[B] = {
    def newDefiner(): B = {
      f(cachedDefiner())
    }
    TBD[B](newDefiner)
  }

  def flatMap[B](f: A => Determine[B]): Determine[B] = {
    f(cachedDefiner())
  }

  def filter(p: A => Boolean): Determine[A] = {
    if (p(cachedDefiner()))
      this
    else
      Unknown
  }

  def foreach(b: A => Unit): Unit = {
    b(cachedDefiner())
  }

  private def cachedDefiner(): A = {
    if (value == null)
      value = definer()
    value
  }
}
case object Unknown extends Determine[Nothing] {
  def map[B](f: Nothing => B): Determine[B] = this
  def flatMap[B](f: Nothing => Determine[B]): Determine[B] = this
  def filter(p: Nothing => Boolean): Determine[Nothing] = this
  def foreach(b: Nothing => Unit): Unit = {}
}
```

I got rid of the set & get and now the TBD class receives instead a function that will define provide the value or null if still undefined. This idea works great for the map method, but the rest of the methods have subtle bugs.

Comment: Not worrying about implementation, can you give some examples on how you would *use* such a monad using `flatMap` or `for` comprehensions? Your implementation is currently lacking the `flatMap` method which would define the semantic on your monad.

Comment: I have updated the question with the test usage I'm giving to it right now. I recognize that my implementation is too clumsy to take advantage of for comprehensions at the moment, basically it is a port of an observer pattern in Java that is missing scala syntactic sugar.

Comment: It's not very clear from your examples what you're trying to accomplish in making the Unknown[A] monad. Can you tell us a little more about the application that will use this library?

Comment: @ilcavero, can you have a look at http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html#23.6 and see how to restructure your code using `flatMap`?

Comment: @DavidY.Ross the idea is to be able to build a bracket of matches, where a match does not necessarily have the contenders or the result defined because the contenders might be still unknown if they depend on the result of previous match, and the result might be known if the game has not been played yet. The monad container allows to abstract the matches away from the fact that the contenders and/or result are unknown.

Comment: @huynhjl I would if I could!, I guess that's where I'm stuck and it is probably because I'm thinking too much in Java. I believe I have an idea using a sub-class of Unknown and making use of closures for the return value of map, but I would need to sit down and try it.

Comment: @ilcavero, perhaps you want to think of the bracket as the container / monad. You "map" over the bracket / tree of "matchups" with a function that takes a matchup and returns a winner.

Comment: The "important" part of the monad is the method bind (flatMap) where you have a M[X] and want to apply a function X=>M[X]. How do you plan to use that? Maybe you don't really need a monad

Comment: @GClaramunt I really can't figure it out on my own that's why I asked the question. Beyond what I planned to use it for, isn't the concept of a To Be Decided value that changes state once (from undefined to defined) a good candidate for a monad?

Comment: Your test snipped is imperative code since you rely on side-effects. You're only calling methods without using their return values.

Comment: @ziggystar agree, with mutability you don't need anything special

Comment: @ziggystar agreed, but the I noticed that this is aggravated by lines like 'definedUnplayedMatch.winner.apply(undefinedUnplayedMatch.home.set(_))' that are unnecessary because 'val undefinedUnplayedMatch = Match(definedUnplayedMatch.winner, definedPlayedMatch.winner, Unknown(null))' is equivalent and less imperative. A match will always return the same winner, just that it will be undefined inside the Unknown monad initially

Answer (score 2):

For a simple approach, you don't need monads, with partial application is enough:

```
//some utilities
type Score=(Int,Int)
case class MatchResult[Team](winner:Team,loser:Team)

//assume no ties
def playMatch[Team](home:Team,away:Team)(score:Score)= 
  if (score._1>score._2) MatchResult(home,away) 
  else MatchResult(away,home)

//defined played match
val dpm= playMatch("D","E")(1,0)
//defined unplayed match, we'll apply the score later
val dum= playMatch("A","B")_

// a function that takes the dum score and applies it 
// to get a defined played match from  an undefined one
// still is a partial application of match because we don't have the final result yet
val uumWinner= { score:Score => playMatch (dpm.winner,dum(score).winner) _ }
val uumLoser= { score:Score => playMatch (dpm.loser,dum(score).loser)  _}

//apply the scores 
uumWinner (2,4)(3,1)
uumLoser (2,4)(0,1)


//scala> uumWinner (2,4)(3,1)
//res6: MatchResult[java.lang.String] = MatchResult(D,B)
//scala> uumLoser (2,4)(0,1)
//res7: MatchResult[java.lang.String] = MatchResult(A,E)
```

This is a starting point, I'm pretty sure it can be further refined. Maybe there we'll find the elusive monad. But I think an applicative functor will be enough.
I'll give another pass later...

Comment: this is a very interesting alternative, the major weakness I see is that it is imposing an order in the definition of the results, and also it is harder to visualize the bracket progression without Match objects.